# uparrow with tail

Tags: arrows

Good morning!

Is it possible to have an uparrow with tail?

I tried rotate package, but I don't like so much the result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

$ \uparrow $ Up arrow with no tail

$ \rightarrowtail $ Right arrow with no tail 

$ f$ \begin{rotate}{90}$\rightarrowtail $ \end{rotate}$\varDelta$ Up arrow with tail, but in wrong position.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank's in advanced!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox` to adjust the vertical position manually (you can give the offset as an argument). If you don't want to figure out the right offset by hand, you can follow [Mico's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473289/uparrow-with-tail/473292#comment1193626_473292) and use `\vcenter` and `\hbox` to vertically center the arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}

% \newcommand\uparrowtail{%
% \raisebox{-.75ex}{\rotatebox{90}{\rightarrowtail}}%
% }

% Or, as Mico suggested, with `\vcenter` instead of `\raisebox`:

\newcommand\uparrowtail{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\rotatebox{90}{\rightarrowtail}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\uparrow$ Uparrow with no tail

$\uparrowtail$ Uparrow with tail

Both next to each other $\uparrow \uparrowtail$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution would be using the symbols provided by `MnSymbol`, which includes a very nice and matching `\uparrowtail`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

$\uparrow$ Uparrow with no tail

$\uparrowtail$ Uparrow with tail

Both next to each other $\uparrow \uparrowtail$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's for your answer! I 'm sorry, but I can't compile your code. It's shows me an error.

Comment: Which error in particular?

Comment: Instead of using a `\raisebox` instruction, you might also try `\newcommand{\uparrowtail}{\vcenter{\hbox{\rotatebox{90}{$\rightarrowtail$}}}}`.

Comment: @Mico good idea, thanks. That's better than finding the right offset by hand

Comment: @DG' I copy-paste your code in a new document, but I had error warnings. So in the main document.